# Trouble installing libqt4-dev on Ubuntu Karmic

Tags: installation, ubuntu-9.10, apt-get

I'm having trouble installing libqt4-dev on Ubuntu Karmic. Here's the output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

  libqt4-core: Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2) but it is not going to be installed
  libqt4-dev: Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-qt3support (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-network (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-svg (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-webkit (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-sql (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-script (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-scripttools (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-help (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-assistant (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-test (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2 is to be installed
              Depends: qt4-qmake (= 4.5.3really4.5.2-0ubuntu1.1) but 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2 is to be installed
  libqt4-test: Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2) but it is not going to be installed
  libqt4-xmlpatterns: Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2) but it is not going to be installed
```

I would really appreciate detailed instructions/suggestions.